# Stats of connectedComponents in OpenCV2

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing

I want to use the coordinates of the components from the connectedComponents with stats in opencv to use it as slicer for an image on which i can then process cv2.findContours following a cv2.minAreaRect. But my problem is that the stats:

```
cv2.CC_STAT_LEFT, cv2.CC_STAT_TOP, cv2.CC_STAT_WIDTH, cv2.CC_STAT_WIDTH, cv2.CC_STAT_HEIGHT
```

dont give me the right positions of the component. For example:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
img = np.zeros((30,30),dtype=np.uint8)
img[10:21,10:21] = 1
img[20,21] = 1
img[21,21] = 1
img[20,22] = 1
img[21,22] = 1
numLabels, labelMatrix, stats, centroids = cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(img, 8, cv2.CV_8UC1)
coods = np.argwhere(labelMatrix == 1)
print(min(coods[:,0]),max(coods[:,0]),min(coods[:,1]),max(coods[:,1]))
print(stats[1][cv2.CC_STAT_TOP],(stats[1][cv2.CC_STAT_TOP]+stats[1][cv2.CC_STAT_WIDTH]),stats[1][cv2.CC_STAT_LEFT],(stats[1][cv2.CC_STAT_LEFT]+stats[1][cv2.CC_STAT_HEIGHT]))
```

**Output**

```
10 21 10 22
10 23 10 22
```

In this small example the x max position just differs with a value of 2 but in some cases they differ a lot more. Now Im wonder why is that? Because i do have to calculate the connectedComponentWithStats anyway i want to use those coordinates and dont use numpy argwhere.

Comment: You are adding TOP and WIDTH instead of TOP and HEIGHT.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have your height and width swapped.

Try this:

```py
print(
(stats[1][cv2.CC_STAT_TOP]), 
(stats[1][cv2.CC_STAT_TOP]+stats[1][cv2.CC_STAT_HEIGHT]),
(stats[1][cv2.CC_STAT_LEFT]),
(stats[1][cv2.CC_STAT_LEFT]+stats[1][cv2.CC_STAT_WIDTH]))
```

If you swap out this line with your last line you get:

```
10 21 10 22
10 22 10 23
```

You'll notice that you're still 1 off from the original, and that is because the CC results are exclusive while the min/max are inclusive.